# Html tag if multilang is decided individually

Tags: html, translation

I just learned html and wrote some java script to replace strings according to the language. So what would be a useful tag to set? Is it useful to use something like lang="en|de" ?

Edit: No, this is no duplicate. I dont have a mixed language site. I just have one site that sets the language depending on the browser language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What <html lang=""> attribute value should I use for a mixed language page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076837/what-html-lang-attribute-value-should-i-use-for-a-mixed-language-page)

Comment: Thats no duplicate. I dont have mixed language.

Comment: Fair enough. The point is that you should only list one language: `a valid BCP 47 language tag, or the empty string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lang` attribute should describe the language of the content.

If you change the content with JavaScript (to content in a different language) then change the value of the `lang` attribute at the same time.